# Group by Field Sharepoint in GridView

Tags: sharepoint-server, list-view-web-part, grouping

I have a list "A" with a text field "category", I wrote a Visual Webpart to create a ListView or Gridview which group by "category" , How can I display inb the header just once the category ? and here is my code (ascx, ascx.cs)
`

```
public void getInfo1()
        {


      SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url);
            SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
            SPList list = web.Lists["List Report 2"];
            SPQuery Q = new SPQuery();
            Q.Query = "<GroupBy Collapse='FALSE'><FieldRef Name='htes' /></GroupBy><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Title' Ascending='true' /></OrderBy>";


            Q.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Title'/>" + "<FieldRef Name='htes'/>" + "<FieldRef Name='FileRef'/>";
            SPListItemCollection item = list.GetItems(Q);

            ListView1.DataSource = item.GetDataTable();
            ListView1.DataBind();

ascx

<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" EnableModelValidation="True"  >

  <LayoutTemplate>
                <p>
                    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="groupPlaceHolder">

                        </asp:PlaceHolder>
                </p>
            </LayoutTemplate>

                <ItemTemplate>

                  <div>

<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "htes")%>
                    </div>
                              <div>
                        <a href='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FileRef")%>'>
                                <p class="title">
                                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Title")%>
                                </p>


                            </a>


                    </div>

                </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>`
```

[image]

Comment: <listview.... <ItemTemplate><div><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "htes")%></div><div><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Title")%></div>

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list and group by is applied on Category. The resultant OOB SharePoint list view already shows the data in a manner described by you.

However if you really want to create a gridview of your own then you can achieve the task using ASP.NET Gridview/Repeater but in that case you need lot of customization in your code. You may go for some third party assembly like [this](http://www.agrinei.com/gridviewhelper/gridviewhelper_en.htm). But my real suggestion would be using a client side library like [Kendo UI](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/index), format the data as JSON using the server side code or fetch the data using default sharepoint web services